# Как узнать значение в столбце таблицы базы данных и поработать с ним? (Postgresql, Go)

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang

В одной из функций в коде я с помощью insert вносил значения в базу данных. Для лучшего понимания уточню. Таблица выглядит так:

Name | Blocked_Amount | Charged_Amount |

Vasya |10 000____________|____________________|

Данные в таблицу занесены, далее мне нужно в другой функции (более того в другом хэндлере), что усложняет задачу внести данные в столбец Charged_Amount, но при этом он не должен быть больше Blocked_AMount, а значит прежде чем вносить данные в этот столбец я должен это число сравнить с уже внесенным в таблицу

Если есть возможность как то вытащить это число из базы данных сравнить со входящими данными в моем коде и затем произвести запись в БД, то расскажите пожалуйста как

Если бы это нужно было сделать в пределе одного Хэндлера, то все просто, но в разных не пойму как

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что можно использовать один запрос, думаю что то типа такого

```
cursor.execute("""
  UPDATE main SET (charged_amount=$1) WHERE $1 < blocked_amount and name = $2;
""", ["vasya", 1]
```

У меня получилось так:

```
select * from main;
  name  | blocked_amount | charged_amount 
--------+----------------+----------------
 vasya  |              1 |              1
 vasya2 |              3 |              4
 vasya2 |              3 |               
 vasya2 |              3 |              7
 vasya2 |              3 |              9
 vasya5 |              1 |               
 vasya5 |                |              1
```

```
UPDATE main SET charged_amount = -2 WHERE -2 < blocked_amount and name = 'vasya5';
UPDATE 1
```

```
select * from main;
  name  | blocked_amount | charged_amount 
--------+----------------+----------------
 vasya  |              1 |              1
 vasya2 |              3 |              4
 vasya2 |              3 |               
 vasya2 |              3 |              7
 vasya2 |              3 |              9
 vasya5 |                |              1
 vasya5 |              1 |             -2
(7 rows)
```

Comment: Ну тогда можно просто достать blocked_amount - SELECT name, blocked_amount FROM TABLE_NAME;
Дальше обработать это уже в go и дальше сделать update

Comment: попробую сейчас на деле и уточню, что по заданию мне нужно расписать разные варианты событий. 1) когда charged меньше block и мы записываем ее в БД 2) когда charged = blocked и мы тоже записываем в БД 3) когда charged > blocked и мы выдаем ошибку.

Comment: Вы сказали, что можно достать blocked amount из таблицы, обработать в go и снова update. Как с помощью select его можно достать?

Comment: SELECT name, blocked_amount FROM TABLE_NAME;

Comment: Отдаст что то такое https://ibb.co/HgrPTSs

Comment: я честно говоря недавно начал изучать все это дело и эта команда в psql, но как мне непосредственно в vs code затащить значение из таблицы?

Comment: Пришлите ваш код - подскажу

Comment: https://github.com/leeyaal/paymentgateway   здесь правда нет коннекта с БД, но в хэндлере Charge вы увидите какие ситуации с Amount я рассматриваю и как все это делал с помощью структур и мапы, но теперь нужно с БД

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос: У вас есть данные которое приходят в программу откуда-то помимо бд и вам нужно эти данные сверить с тем что в бд.

```
type Data struct {
    item string
}

var dbconnect string = "host=localhost port=5432 user=dbowner dbname=name sslmode=disable password=password"

func GetData(id string) []Data {
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dbconnect)
    rowsData, _ := db.Query("select <нужное поле таблицы> from <TableName> where id=$1", id)
    db.Close()
    var Na []Data
    for rowsData.Next() {
        n := Data{}
        rowsData.Scan(&n.item)
        Na = append(Na, n)
    }
    rowsData.Close()
    return Na
}
```

Дальше пройдите по массиву и получите значение поля.

```
func Rang(id string) {
    data := GetData(id)
    for _, it := range data {
        fmt.Println(it)
    }
}
```

C it можете сверять другие переменные так как it это как раз то что было в значении поля в бд и теперь оно просто переменная. Код не проверял, но должен работать.